# Chrome 39 unreliably responding to drop-down menus?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We have not made any changes to the site, yet the JS drop down menus are not working about 2/3 of the time.  Sometimes they still display when clicked, but usually they just don't respond.  I have checked JavaScript settings (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?hl=en), disabled the extensions, and tried everything else I can think of.

Just upgraded from 38.0.2 to 39.0 this morning, so I suspect that's the issue.

IE9/10/11 and Firefox are working fine.

Win7 x64 machine.

Comment: Sidenote: [there is now a stable release of Chrome x64](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/?platform=win64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Task Manager showed extra chrome.exe*32 processes running in the background.  Forcing those to close (End Process) cleared up the problem.

Comment: Those are there because each Chrome tab is technically it's own process. I doubt that had anything to directly do with your issue aside from freeing up RAM. Those processes will spawn again when needed.

Comment: maybe...  I suspect that one of the background tabs was having issues, and closing them all out cleared it up.    https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1184722?hl=en